# FileNotFoundError while installing pocketsphinx via anaconda

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

```
C:\Windows\System32>"C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3
6-32\python.exe" -m pip install pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Requirement 'pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but
 the file does not exist
Processing c:\windows\system32\pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\download.py", line 715, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "C:\Users\Dinesh Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 482, in unzip_file
    zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\
pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl'
```

This was the error when I typed those 2 commands. I have the file in the right directory but it is showing like file does not exist.

I have downloaded the right file according to the following commands.

```
"C:\Users\krush\Anaconda3\python.exe" --version
"C:\Users\krush\Anaconda3\python.exe" -c "importstruct;print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
```

Comment: python -m pip install pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

Comment: Note that titles of "please help me" are not only useless, but they require someone to make them useful. They therefore create work. Please always use useful titles on Stack Overflow, and on any other sites that require a title for something.

Answer (score 1):

download it from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pocketsphinx
then install the package by following command:
python -m pip install pocketsphinx-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl